# httpRuntime vs Compilation in web.config - targetFramework for ASP.NET web site

Tags: web-config, .net-4.8, target-framework, httpruntime

I have upgraded an ASP.NET web site application from .NET Framework 4.0 to 4.8 using visual studio 2019

I deployed the application to IIS with this configuration in the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
```

Is this setting enough for my website to work properly for clients?
I read somewhere that I need also to set the httpRuntime tag and not just the compilation tag as follows:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
```

My questions:

1- if I skipped this httpRuntime settings, then at what framework will the application work in the client side and on server side (IIS)? I suppose the server will use the compilation tag setting of 4.8 to compile and run the web site, but what about the client(question 2)?

2- if I skipped this httpRuntime settings and the client has a .NET RunTime framework less than 4.8 (maybe 4.5) then does this give an error in the browser?

3- if the answer for question 2 is yes, then how to fix it? should I add httpRuntime setting of a lower framework in this case? like this:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

plus the compilation tag of course?

4- can I omit the compilation tag completely? and keep only the httpRuntime? or this could result in my web site application can't be compiled in the server?

Please help in best practice for these 2 confusing configuration
Thank You